# Is it possible that a PDE solved by two different analytical methods with same Initial and boundary values give different results?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I have developed two models of same scenario. Both models involve a PDE which is solved with same Initial and Boundary conditions. In one model it is solved with Laplace transform and in other with Fourier. After applying both  solutions for real field data one model (Fourier transform) is giving a bit different (and queer) results. I have checked all the mathematical steps, coding and field data but could not find a mistake. I don't know this change in results is due to some error by me or the limitation of the method which is used to solve this equation?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues here. The first one is rather mathematical: your PDE + initial and boundary conditions could be ill-posed, that is, there could exist multiple solutions. It's not very easy to determine this by looking at the PDE; moreover, for physical applications, this is often regarded as a sign that the model is flawed.

Assuming that your model (PDE + conditions) is well-posed, and should therefore have a unique solution, the second issue could be the numerical implementation of the analytical results. I assume you applied both methods correctly, and that the result you obtained from both is exact. However, the numerical implementation of such expressions is of course never exact. A series gets truncated at a certain order, an integral is approximated using a certain numerical scheme, functions are calculated using a finite size grid, and so on. A famous problem regarding a finite number of terms in a Fourier expansion is the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon), which I would classify as 'a bit queer'.

It might be worth it to add a few details to your question, because as it stands, it's not clear how the results you obtain are unexpected.

Comment: The equation is Diffusion equation and the exact problem with Fourier model (fst) is that it always give simulated signal similar to that of input instead of observed one. While other model (Laplace) gives simulated signal closer to that of observed. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwk0jctise9xwj2/River%20to%20B2_2.tif?dl=0)fst represent fourier model and stlk1 represent Laplace model. 'fst opt' represent optimized values of  parameters and then same values were used for 'stlk1 opt' but 'fst opt' is no way near to observed but rather it is same in pattern as that of input signal.

Comment: Regarding numerical implementation: I am also skeptical about this and asked the question about possible error in my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875497/writing-matlab-code-to-approximate-integration-by-trapezoidal-rule) but have not obtained any answer.